# how to use UISwitch in Categories?

Tags: objective-c

im trying to use UISwitch using category.
In my catogory class:

```
@implementation UISwitch(Analytics)

-(void) addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents{
 [super addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:controlEvents];
}
```

here i have a problem in capturing the event.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you probably shouldn't be going about it this way. From the docs:

> Although the language currently allows
>   you to use a category to override
>   methods the class inherits, or even
>   methods declared in the class
>   interface, you are strongly
>   discouraged from using this
>   functionality.

Among the reasons given for why are:

> When a category overrides an inherited
>   method, the method in the category
>   can, as usual, invoke the inherited
>   implementation via a message to super.
>   However, if a category overrides a
>   method that already existed in the
>   category's class, there is no way to
>   invoke the original implementation.

and

> A category cannot reliably override
>   methods declared in another category
>   of the same class. This issue is of
>   particular significance since many of
>   the Cocoa classes are implemented
>   using categories. A framework-defined
>   method you try to override may itself
>   have been implemented in a category,
>   and so which implementation takes
>   precedence is not defined.

Either of those might be in play with your example.

If you really do want to capture *all* UISwitch behavior for your analytics (rather than just individual ones), you're better off using a custom subclass of UISwitch. If you need to patch this into a large existing project and want to keep using UISwitch as the class name everywhere, you can take try class posing. But that is perhaps a last resort, since it is a fairly heavy-handed technique.